# how to step through debugger with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm using bluebird promises in my node code and frequently use the debugger to step through code. however, using promises, I find I can't step through like I'm used to. I'd have to add break points like i have commented below.

```
        var promise = doSomethingAndReturnPromise1(stuff);
        promise.then(function(stuff) {
            return doSomethingAndReturnPromise2(stuff) /* add brk pt */
        }).then(function(user) {
            return doSomethingAndReturnPromise3(stuff) /* add brk pt */
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // handle err /* add brk pt */
        }
```

I recall when using `async`, I was able to step through without adding the additional break points, or could set a break point and more easily tell from the stack what happened before. Is there a way to enable that in bluebird or any promise library?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside `doSomethingAndReturnPromise()` body?

Comment: @moonwave99 yeah, that is essentially what I'm doing. but ideally, I'd like to step forward through the code, opposed to setting a breakpoint and running to the breakpoint. so just image setting a break point on the first line and being able to step, step by step all the way to the final return and out of the promise. is that making sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can step through bluebird promises:

1. Turn off the batching trampoline by turning on `Promise.longStackTraces()` or otherwise putting bluebird in debug mode (by setting the environment variable `BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1` ).
2. Turn on async stack traces by opening the developer tools, going to the "Sources" tab and clicking "Async".
3. Debug away.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for writing. I currently use longStackTraces but have not been able to step from one `then` to another `then` without breakpoints. am i doing something wrong? I added a comment above, because I might have not worded my question well.

Comment: How would it know to continue to the next `then`, are you certain you don't have any actions in the interim? What version of node are you using?

Comment: for node version, i'm on 0.12.6 .  as for the next, then, yes, i would like to step through all the actions in the interim. I made a video of my kind of silly workflow (realizing my original q was worded wrong) , where i'm setting breakpoints after every promise i enter, where i would ideally like to step into a promise and out of one and onto the next then, into a promise, and so on. at the end of the vid, i just step through code which isn't super relevant to me. what would be cool is the ability to step into the promise and out and in , ... https://vimeo.com/140347340

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your advice. AWS elastic bean stalk doesn't support 4.0 yet, but once they do, I'll definitely give it a shot!